# PEM Public file convert to string [Swift]

Tags: swift, kotlin, mobile

Hi guys  questions about the Public/Private certificate using swift. when i run kotlin  to generate a PublicKey i get something like this

[Kotlin code]

```
 val keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA")
 keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048)
 val keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()
 val rsaPublicKey: RSAPublicKey = keyPair.public as RSAPublicKey
 Srintln("public: " + String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(rsaPublicKey.encoded)))
```

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuykzvfk0W26ch/TC2HzuGJay/fBZ5KTc9YeBtYfO+evkwI+T0kVpXfAHbMr7AQWBLzuaQ3vf7lvZoo+XeyRbOG5yT+jQItTvRhC77ZxdTOcBlwJAaVDtmMWXAvB0QxLtz9c9LUDQLOnaliI2PSTl3PtHsfj/mBD0U+TY6Fp47rf73Ts/l0d/3aJ9C8ZYdWt5VWd2uBnKUpUR5A8AGcIJivAY2EkwkZ01Lh54HVYBOwxbHXpcjBVxXUHMRp/gAFq2V9jM07Hlx4s4Eaa+j0wiWADsakbbnuOS4CVhsbdsy7Vs+jdFh5AlZ2PVldfUaJBr3L1lT4RgliixyAvINR4YGQIDAQAB
```

and when i run in Ios i get a shorter version of the base64, any reason why is that? it's something about 30 less characters

[Swift code]

```
can be found in this comment [using same size 2048]
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61377864/3569968
```

```
MIIBCgKCAQEAqWS+wJPvAbddIvdg0PFgY5U2Fr8bpg0eAEKwAD2bputQoY1Fn6lZwCuU8soakO/anIIX7dLDkGd+tnNc9w6D46i21PDFORy+gzLHYzUNt5lr82bm6pvn6SS0/WzwTLaWvHWNLhLffEyXauX/8M+AJFsQvGMYbP2bnVeHmgvzYF0/r7kaQrUpkD5rhXrMAS8FUbHrcXwFb6dFKAhFgon5I+ORrUkBpWnTITmGRceXsDGGvgSnTTdgGqxPPlfZ/nnxBjyha1tH2HQE/Tpfx9oqg+63w80SM9BsU3TvPD95bIHTWHUtp2Cg3+rMOV4yV/t8OSvWdCgXTyQDl0N2kIm8hwIDAQAB
```

code i used for ios can be found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61377864/3569968
also
https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA

Comment: And with different base64 encoding options?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. Linking to GitHub projects and other SO questions does not count as a [mcve].

Comment: doen, is that good enough?