# python RSA encrypt differs from JSEncrypt?

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, jsencrypt

I am writing a crawler using python. The website uses JSEncrypt to encrypt password. The JS code is as follows:

```
var pubkey = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDB3Xn/+WP5OVbA8hCj3zuTlqAJ+CVt5UPHi1TYTbsBzEZ0W0+tgn9YElA9hNIi5ElFTicpGCYW4w+B2zmniSLKy3sqItT1wNCt6zGJ7lkUCkhLSIY4mp9Tqs8hn01/3HNnqDRBPhFcmA99Vy+SOoTUvCOUMiGp4ENruyxkvEp5vwIDAQAB"
var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
encrypt.setKey(pubkey)
encrypt.encrypt("123")
```

And my python codes are:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import base64
pubkey = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDB3Xn/+WP5OVbA8hCj3zuTlqAJ
+CVt5UPHi1TYTbsBzEZ0W0+tgn9YElA9hNIi5ElFTicpGCYW4w+B2zmniSLKy3sq
ItT1wNCt6zGJ7lkUCkhLSIY4mp9Tqs8hn01/3HNnqDRBPhFcmA99Vy+SOoTUvCOU
MiGp4ENruyxkvEp5vwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''
rsa_key = RSA.importKey(pubkey)
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(rsa_key)
print base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt("123"))
```

But their results are different. Also, I found that these codes produce different encryption output each time called. With the same key and plaintext, shouldn't rsa algorithm return the same output?

Comment: BTW: JSEncryption can be found http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/example.html here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running JSEncrypt twice, are the outputs the same?

In theory, the outputs should be different every time.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16329374

Comment: One measure to verify is that you should be able to decrypt the data using the right private key.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't focus on comparing results**, **It will not same**, it's **different** every time you run encrypt. Modify like this, it's should work event if the result not the same,

```
print base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(b'123')).decode()
```