# how to make c openssl generate the same signed text as JAVA SHA256withRSA/PSS Signature?

Tags: java, c, openssl, rsa, signing

I am working on rpc call signing, and to make server accept our API calls, we need to use RSAPrivateKey to sign http mime headers.  Server side code is written in JAVA and use "SHA256withRSA/PSS" to verify signature.

My problem is I got different signing hashes from JAVA and c openssl code.  So the question is, is it possible for openssl to generate the same signing hash as JAVA?

JAVA code:

```
public static String getSignedString(PrivateKey privateKey, String text) throws Exception {
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA/PSS", "BC");
    sig.initSign(privateK);
    sig.update(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    byte[] signed = sig.sign();

    String result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signed);
    System.out.println("signed : " + result);
    /// signed result works perfect.
}
```

c code:

```
bool RSASign(RSA* rsa, const unsigned char* Msg, size_t MsgLen,unsigned char** EncMsg,size_t* MsgLenEnc) {
EVP_MD_CTX* m_RSASignCtx = EVP_MD_CTX_create();
EVP_PKEY* priKey  = EVP_PKEY_new();
EVP_PKEY_CTX *pctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(priKey, NULL);

EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(pctx, RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING);  
// tried RSA_PKCS1_PADDING w/o success.
EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(priKey, rsa);
if (EVP_DigestSignInit(m_RSASignCtx,&pctx, EVP_sha256(), NULL,priKey)<=0) {
    return false;
}
if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(m_RSASignCtx, Msg, MsgLen) <= 0) {
    return false;
}
if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, NULL, MsgLenEnc) <=0) {
    return false;
}
*EncMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(*MsgLenEnc);
if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(m_RSASignCtx, *EncMsg, MsgLenEnc) <= 0) {
    return false;
}
// here EncMsg is different from JAVA output, server validation failed. need to make it the same as JAVA output.
}
```

Comment: RSA-PSS signatures are randomized so each signing operation should produce a different signature on the message. Also see [Are RSA signatures unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5883451/608639)

Comment: If you want RSA-PSS for both OpenSSL and Java, then see [RSA-PSS signing with OpenSSL and Bouncycastle](https://work-now-dammit.blogspot.com/2010/04/rsa-pss-signing-with-openssl-and.html). If you want the same signature from both both OpenSSL and Java, then use RSA-SSA with PKCS padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "PSS" in "RSA-PSS" stands for ***probabilistic** signature scheme* -- it's a randomized algorithm. You aren't supposed to get the same signature every time.

Comment: There's also this question in the body: *"is it possible for openssl to generate the same signing hash as JAVA"*. That's a different question than the one in the title, and the same hash should be produced by each library. But I'm not sure if ... OP used the wrong terminology for the body's question. That is, they are the same question and "signature" should have been used instead of "hash". Another possibility is, OP truly wants the same signature for both OpenSSL and Java, so they should use RSA-SSA and PKCS v1 padding.

Comment: Got it. I will open a new question. Actually what i am expecting is JAVA could verify my openssl PSS signature.